# No retrieving data when fetching data with Vuejs using laravel with relationship

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, eloquent, axios

In controller, the response is ok 200

```
return = CustomerRequest::with('item')->paginate(5);
```

in model class

```
public function item()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Item');
}
```

In Vuejs Template

```
data() {
    columns: {},
},
methods: {
    getData() {
        axios.get('/api/customerRequest')
             .then(response => {
                  this.columns = response.data;
              });
    }
}


<tr v-for="column in columns" :key="column.id">
<td>{{column.id}}</td>
<td>{{column.item.title}}</td>
...
</tr>
```

I get an error:

> TypeError: "column.item is null"

Comment: you are using `return = CustomerRequest::with('item')->paginate(5);` or `return CustomerRequest::with('item')->paginate(5);`?

Comment: without equal = :)

Comment: Do a `console.log(response.data)` and check the value of item in the response payload

Comment: i do this
the output is json object 
0{
id : 1
name: admin
item: {
id:1
title: some
}
i can't access to item

Answer (score 0):

You have a type when you are setting `this.columns`.

Update `this.colums = response.data;` in:

```
methods: {
  getData(){
  axios.get('/api/customerRequest').then(response => {
    this.columns = response.data;
  });
}
```